# Hebrew names and English names

Tags: history, names, hebrew

I have just visited my great grandfather's grave and discovered his Hebrew name was Yehuda Leib, yet in England he was known as Louis Goodman. Is there a connection between the names? He moved to England from Kiev about 1895, would he have been known as Goodman (or equivalent) in Kiev? His fathers name was Meir what would be a likely English equivalent?

Comment: A person's Hebrew name doesn't always reflect their English one. I've known many people where this wasn't the case. For instance, I once met a man named James and his Hebrew name was Yehudah, when Ya'akov is in fact the equivalent to James.

Comment: I don't know an etymological connection between Yehuda Leib and Louis, but Louis is one of the common assumed names for 'Leib'. Very likely Goodman was his original surname. Goodman, Guttman, Gottesman (and others) are typical Slavic names (meaning 'Man of God'; similar to the Spanish names Bar-btach or Bar-el). A "likely" equivalent for Meir could be Morris, but there's no *accepted* equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. As it stands now your question does not seem to directly relate to Judaism. It is possible that it will get closed as being beyond the scope of this site ([which is limited to questions that are specifically about Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). You can always [edit] your question to show how it is in fact connected to Judaism.